# Not allowing Google Maps api to place a marker more than once

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I have made a html file which is integrated with javascript which lets me retrieve data for an XML file and plot them coordinates automatically onto the map. It does this because I have a timer placed into the script to tick every 4 sec so that the map can refresh on its own.
Now i would like to be able to not let a marker be placed in the same place twice using a 'lastCoordinate' variable but not sure how to do that my first impression was to make it global then refer back to it.
this is my code for that section;

```
var lastCoordinates();
function gotdata()
{

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        var y = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("y")[0].innerHTML;
        var x = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("x")[0].innerHTML;

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
      });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lastCoordinates` as an object, store for each coordinate a property in the object with a name based on the coordinate, e.g. x+'_'+y;

Before you create a marker check if `lastCoordinates` already contains a property with the particular name:

```
var lastCoordinates={};

function gotdata(){

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

        var d = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement, 
            //innerHTML shouldn't work for XML-Nodes
            y = d.getElementsByTagName("y")[0].textContent,
            x = d.getElementsByTagName("x")[0].textContent,
            h = [x,y].join('_');
        if(lastCoordinates[h]){
          return;
        } 

        lastCoordinates[h]= new google.maps.Marker({
                              //switched x and y
                              //I'm  not sure what x and y are
                              //but a latitude usually is y
                              //and a longitude is x
                              position: new google.maps.LatLng(y,x),
                              map: map,
                              title: 'Hello World!'
                            });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped could you mark up this question because i'm new so i need reputation to have other privileges and because i have accepted your answer